# Using command line to open, edit and save content in file

Tags: json, vim, docker-compose, package.json

During the work, there are a lot of partners in the project, and sometimes I need to switch among different partners a lot, and every time the process:

- change the partner name in .env file manually
- run `docker-compose down` in the terminal
- run `docker-compose up -d` in the terminal
- run `gulp dev --partner <partner name>` in the terminal

**So my question is** :

- Would it possible to use one line of command to complete the entire above process (such as in the package.json, "docker": "docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d", then `npm run docker` means running docker down and up)

**Basically the main point should be** :

- Would it be possible to use command line to open, edit and save a file? (I know I could use command line to open vi, and then to edit inside vi, but here is not the case)

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly methods of text editing from the command line (see sed/awk etc.) My solution to this, would be to have multiple .env files:
e.g. .env.alice; .env.bob; .env.charlie

Then as part of my script I would symbolically link the one I wanted:

```
ln -sf .env.alice .env
```

The rest as you described.